# Python for cryptocurrencies - data structure

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code in Jupyter Note that I like to scrape CoinMarketCap site:

```
     url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/'
     df=pd.read_html(url, header=None)
     df[0]
```

The output used to be a pandas dataframe but now it's a list of 1623 rows × 11 columns and when I try:

```
     df_crypto = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

it returns only the column names. So, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the CoinMarketCap Api instead if you would like to collect this asset data. Currently you are scraping an HTML page and collecting a lot of excess, irrelevent information.

I suggest you do the following:

```
import requests 

r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/')
x = r.json()
```

You can then convert this dictionary into a pandas dataframe

Comment: I did it once... so much paginations... the limit is 100 results per call and there are over 1000 cryptos but it's ok, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the documentation of [**`pandas.read_html`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html#pandas-read-html)

> Returns:  dfs : ***list of DataFrames***

You need to access the desired index of your list (in this case the first index), and drop unnamed columns.

***Example***

```
df = pd.read_html(url)
df = df[0].loc[:, ~df[0].columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
df.head(2)

# Result

   #          Name Symbol        Market Cap     Price Circulating Supply  \
0  1   BTC Bitcoin    BTC  $129,198,417,887  $7576.52           17052475
1  2  ETH Ethereum    ETH   $59,151,386,138   $593.64           99642183

     Volume (24h)    % 1h   % 24h     % 7d
0  $6,196,160,000  -0.40%  -0.32%   -7.55%
1  $2,861,120,000  -0.22%   0.31%  -13.54%
```

Comment: Perfect. Just Fine. A beautiful pandas dataframe.